# Bootstrap affix- keep sidebar within container when position:fixed

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on implementing a sticky sidebar using Bootstrap's affix plugin. The sidebar sticks as expected, but i am having trouble keeping the div within a padded container. When the affix class is applied, the sidebar will jump outside of the container and all the way to the right side of my browser window.

Is there a simple way to keep the sidebar in its correct place?

See demo:

http://bit.ly/1F56C2C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) `affix.bs.affix` and `affix-top.bs.affix` to set value of `right`.

We can add the `.container`'s margin-right and padding-right and set the `right` value of the `#sidebar`

```
$('#sidebar')
  .on('affix.bs.affix', function () {
    var margin =  parseInt($('.container').css("margin-right"));
    var padding = parseInt($('.container').css("padding-right"));
    $("#sidebar").css("right",margin+padding);
  })
  .on('affix-top.bs.affix', function () {
    $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed anpsmn's suggestion but made the following changes:

```
$('#sidebar').on('affix.bs.affix', function(){ 
    var size = $(window).width(); //get browser width
    var divWidth = $(myContainer).width(); //get width of container
    var margin = (size - divWidth) / 2; //get difference and divide by 2
    $("#sidebar").css("right",margin);
})
.on('affix-top.bs.affix', function () {
  $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
});
```

This calculates the amount of space outside of the container as it relates to the browser size. It needs some tweaking but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Made a slight adjustment sl1983 suggestion which has worked for me:

```
$('#sidebar').on('affix.bs.affix', function(){ 
    var size = $(window).width(); //get browser width
    var divWidth = $(myContainer).width(); //get width of container
    var margin = (size - divWidth) / 2; //get difference and divide by 2
    var sidebarWidth = $('#sidebar').width(); //get sidebar width

    $("#sidebar").css("right",margin);
    $("#sidebar1").css("width",sidebarWidth);
})
.on('affix-top.bs.affix', function () {
  $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
});
```

This will also insure that the sidebar preserves its width when it becomes in a "fixed" state.